# Structured request using 'askfor'/'send' - Invalid object_id

Tags: ios, facebook, object, request, action

I'm stuck in a situation where I am not able to use the structured 'askfor' or 'send' requests through IOS SDK. I always get an error which says that facebook could not find any object with that particular object id. I created the object by using the Object Types section under the Open Graph section in the App settings page. I have tried the same thing with test user account too, but no avail.

Used this as the guide - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2#gifting

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 toList, @"to",             // Comma separated string of FB ids.
                                 dataStr, @"data",          // Data to be sent with request
                                 objectId, @"object_id",    // Object as retrieved from Object Types 
                                 @"askfor", @"action_type", // Preset action type [send/askfor/turn]
                                ];
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                              message:messageStr
                                                title:titleStr
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
```

I get an error within the returnUrl (error 100) which says facebook cannot find an object with the given ID.

Have been stuck at this for quite sometime now, any help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your app will just break at 4/30/2015? And why does v2.0 break your system because of ids?

Comment: Yes I understand that, 4/30/2015 is quite far! v2.0 uses app specific tokens which is a change I cannot accommodate right away.

Comment: It is just different ids in different apps. It you only have one app there is no difference

Comment: v2.0 did not help! (edited the question). Same problem.